# Infinite loop on login screen

Tags: release-freya, greeter

Title says it all. I installed some updates yesterday (hadn't updated in around ~6 months) to my Freya (don't laugh) system. Today, whenever I enter my password and press enter, a black screen flashes, and I get sent back to the login screen.

If I enter a terminal and run `cat ~/.xsession-errors`, I get:

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Error while executing session-migration: Failed to execute child process "session-migration" (No such file or directory)
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file remmina-applet.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file nylas-mail.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file user-dirs-update-gtk-pantheon.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file parcellite-startup.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file clipit-startup.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary

(gnome-settings-daemon:5043): media-keys-plugin-WARNING **: Grab failed for some keys, another application may already have access the them.

(gala:5096): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 11

(gala:5115): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 11
gnome-session[4898]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' respawning too quickly
gnome-session[4898]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

(gnome-settings-daemon:5043): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
```

I have *no* clue what's going on  Help!!

Comment: This is the same as here (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13881/long-boot-time-after-recent-updates#comment16864_13881). I "solved" with chown .Xauthority too, but the next reboot I got a similar problem (long boot instead of loop boot)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was easier than I thought...

I just did Ctrl+F1 -> logged in -> `sudo chown ryan:ryan .Xauthority`.

Comment: mark your question to solved if you managed to fix that

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in dbus.

Workaround:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.backup
```

More info:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377 or https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2016-July/msg02793.html